# Наиболее близкий внешне к Windows дистрибутив Linux

Tags: windows, ос, linux

Скажите, какой есть дистрибутив, который очень похож со всеми функциональностями, оформлением, интерфейсом на Windows? Чтобы пользователи даже и не заметили, что работают не на Windows.

Comment: [Mint][1] [1]: http://linuxmint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласен с предыдущим оратором. Единственно можно попробовать перевести на ubuntu, думается она самая простая из линуксов. Если все ставить сразу допиленное под нужды организации, проводить ликбезы и по 300 раз отвечать почему не запускается .exe файл - то рано или поздно "олинуксячите" своих пользователей. Ну и естественно задумайтесь на тему специфичного софта, тк wine - не всегда годное решение.

Answer (score 2):

Таких дистров нет. Тем более по функциональности, ибо Linux это совершенно отличная от винды система, начиная от файловой системы и заканчивая установкой программ.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, надо знать, какие программы будут использованы, какие задачи надо выполнять, например, если надо работать с графикой, складскими программами и т.д. То есть подобрать аналоги вин-программ. Если надо лишь интернет, офисный пакет (*.doc,*.xls) и распечать документы, то самое легкое в плане перехода - Ubuntu, если надо что-то специфичное, то опять таки надо найти аналог и отсюда уже плясать.

Comment: Да, мне только офисные пакеты+интернет.Попробовал CStrike установить, под вайн, работаеть.Ура!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu? Ни капли схожего с Windows. Unity - это вообще нечто ни на что не похожее. Я бы посоветовал openSUSE (сам пользую) или Fedora, c кедами (KDE). Кеды можно настроить очень похоже на Windows. Ну конечно же рамки окон такие же, меню Пуск и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Юнити вообще странное, лучше бунту с Гномом, но все-равно это не тот винлинукс,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xandros#PrestoК примеру, етсь еще много примеров, русский даже дистрибьютив,но тут правильно сказали что нужно знать ЧТО нужно делать на этой осида  и скольк  пользователей, био если очень ммного то всем обьяснять почему там нету того или того и почему не открываются *.exe просто замучаешсяХХотя не много людей приучить вполне можно, главное желание  и ресурсы)

Answer (score 0):

Порекомендую Linux Mint с Gnome 2. Наиболее просто будет пересаживать.

Answer (score 0):

[Ylmf OS 1.0](http://it-master.biz/ylmf-os-1-0)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте linuxXP ну или runtu.

Answer (score 0):

Есть много дистрибутивов, копирующих интерфейс Win. Debian семерочка или Синклер Линукс. Оба достаточно близко копируют интерфейс и функциональность, но игры будут идти с трудом, а некоторые вообще не пойдут. Хотя программы можно запустить (большинство). Для игр подходит Искра 14.4 (последняя от разработчиков ИнтеграЛ), но они очень требовательны к ресурсам системы. LinXP не советую, он платный, функционал ниже среднего. Есть ещё сборки, но вышеперечисленные мне лично больше всего понравились, хотя это моё личное мнение!

Comment: Да, Sinclair Win 7 действительно очен похож.Спасибо